# How to redirect root folder as subfolder to site?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, rest, api, virtualhost

I am trying to implement the Wordpress REST API with React. Modern convention seems to be to set an API as a subfolder to a domain, i.e.

```
https://sitename.com/api/v1

I want to be able to go to 
https://sitename.com/api/v1/wp-admin

And be able to sign into wordpress and have it so the REST api is accessed like:

https://sitename.com/api/v1/wp-json/wp/v2/pages
```

I have this file structure:

[image]

Inside `api/` is the wordpress install.  If I include the api inside the public folder and point towards the build folder with the virtual host, it works as desired, except for the fact that when I build the React app it clears the Wordpress install and restarts that whole process.

I tried setting the virtual host to the subfolder, but it is still returning a 404.

Edit: To get a simple instance of this running:

```
yarn create-react-app dir_name
cd dir_name
mkdir api
cd api
wp core download
# Add virtual host
# Generate SSL Cert
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I've came up with is attaching a symbolic link to the `api/` directory and linking it to the `build/` directory.

```
# Source->Destination
ln -s /var/www/site.com/public/api /var/www/site.com/build/
```

Depending on your configuration you may have to change `api/` group once you do a `yarn build` for the server to have access for Wordpress (to add plugins for example).

Quick run through:

```
ln -s /var/www/site.com/api /var/www/site.com/public/
yarn build/
sudo chown -R :www-data build/
```

Edit: I recently adopted what feels like a better approach that uses the apache virtual host.

First, I segmented my root directory into `frontend` and a `backend` directory. Inside frontend is the output from `create-react-app`. Inside `backend` is `api/wp`.  I nested Wordpress inside an api directory incase the project were to ever expand and include multiple apis, they would all be grouped in one place.

Here is the directory structure

[image]
[image]

Inside the backend .htaccess is a redirect to the wordpress install

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/wp
RewriteRule (.*) wp/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Inside wordpress is a blank theme I made that redirects to the react app url, in this case, isma.test.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you install WordPress in the /api subfolder, that is considered root for the WP instance so no prefix will be added to the REST API endpoint.

To achieve that, you should use the "rest_url_prefix" filter. Something like:

```
add_filter( 'rest_url_prefix', 'change_api_slug');
function change_api_slug( $slug ) {

    return 'api';

}
```

Here is a pretty good article: https://buddydev.com/modifying-api-base-url-prefix-for-wp-rest-api-plugin/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That doesn't really address my question.  My virtual host is returning 404 for the wordpress install inside the api/ folder.  I feel this is because the React App is already using the domain and so there is a conflict with the domain.  I've solved it currently by adding a symbolic link to the build folder, but i feel that isn't the correct way to solve it.